# How to I store grpc encoded data in a Java String?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java, envoyproxy

I need issue the following in Java:

// I want to store the following in a String:

```
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x15{“message”:”Hello”}’
```

The whole thing I will execute is as below but I first need to just get the String above stored into StringArray or whatever works. This is grpc encoding I need to use Envoy proxy http-grpc bridge.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/grpc+json”  http://10.20.1.10:31234/com.test.echo.EchoService/echo -d '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x15{“message”:”Hello”}’
```

I am particular concerned with how to strong represent the last last part after -d in a String so I can send it across. How do I store this in Java?

UPDATE; I have tried:

```
String content = "x00x00x00x00x15{“message”:”Hello”}";
```

and

```
 String content = "//x00//x00//x00//x00//x15{“message”:”Hello”}";
```

But both give back grpc 13 code and

```
  Jul 23, 2019 6:41:36 AM    io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerStream$TransportState deframeFailed
WARNING: Exception processing message
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: gRPC frame header malformed: reserved bits not zero
at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:524)
at       io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.processHeader(MessageDeframer.java:377)
```

Comment: You mean `\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x15{“message”:”Hello”}`?

Comment: I tried that but I get error on server side;

Comment: WARNING: Exception processing message
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: gRPC frame header malformed: reserved bits not zero
 at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:524)
 at io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.processHeader(MessageDeframer.java:377)
 at io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.deliver(MessageDeframer.java:267)
 at io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.request(MessageDeframer.java:

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl ? This makes sending grpc requests much easier! `grpcurl --plaintext -d '{...}' 10.20.1.10:31234 com.test.echo.EchoService/echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you solved this step base on [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159484/what-does-encountered-end-of-stream-mid-frame-mean-when-it-spits-this-out-on-the/57191421#57191421).

btw, you can use ByteBuffer

```
byte[] payload = ???;
int payloadSize = payload.length;
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(payloadSize + 5);
buf.put((byte) 0);
buf.putInt(payloadSize);
buf.but(payload);
```